# HTML Range element to change CSS image filter with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, range, imagefilter

I am trying to use JavaScript to change an image's CSS filter when a user selects a new value on a range element.  My HTML does not seem to work though.
Here are my CSS image styles:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> <style>
img {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%);}
</style> </head>
```

Here are my image and range elements :

```
<body>
<img src="pineapple.jpg" id="Image" alt="Pineapple" width="300" 
height="300">

<form>
Photo Filter:
  <input type="range" id="Filter" name="points" min="0" max="10" 
onclick="ChangeFilter()">

</form>
```

Here is my JavaScript function to change the CSS image style:

```
<script>
function ChangeFilter() {
Image = document.getElementById("Image").style.filter;

Filter = document.getElementById("Filter").value;
if (Filter == 1) {Image = grayscale(10%);}
if (Filter == 2) {Image = grayscale(20%);}
if (Filter == 3) {Image = grayscale(30%);}
if (Filter == 4) {Image = grayscale(40%);}
if (Filter == 5) {Image = grayscale(50%);}
if (Filter == 6) {Image = grayscale(60%);}
if (Filter == 7) {Image = grayscale(70%);}
if (Filter == 8) {Image = grayscale(80%);}
if (Filter == 9) {Image = grayscale(90%);}
if (Filter == 10) {Image = grayscale(100%);}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I select a new value on the range element, the image's style properties just won't respond. Help Please!  Many Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically changing Webkit filter values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297350/dynamically-changing-webkit-filter-values)

Comment: And Possible duplicate of [How to add image filter based on range input value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686604/how-to-add-image-filter-based-on-range-input-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onclick` event to `onchange` in html and in javascript do this:

```
<script>
    var image = document.getElementById("Image");
    var range = document.getElementById("Filter");
    function ChangeFilter() {
        image.style.WebkitFilter = "grayscale(" + range.value*10 + "%)");
        image.style.filter = "grayscale(" + range.value*10 + "%)");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Mehran -
You are a magician!  It works :) Thank You. Thank You. Thank You.

Comment: This way you overwrite all inline styles of the image. Not just the filter value. It should be image.style.WebkitFilter = "grayscale(" + range.value*10 + "%)"

Comment: Note that '.WebkitFilter' won't work in Firefox. To support it, change the '.filter' property as well within your ChangeFilter() function.

Answer (score 1):

**You can find [a working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4t0au3vp/2/).**

There were a few problems in your code:

1) First of all, you should use the `onchange` event instead of the `onclick` event. Or you can use `oninput` event as well.

2) The correct way of assigning new value of the filter to an Image object is `Image.style.WebkitFilter="grayscale(10%)";`.

**JavaScript:**

```
function ChangeFilter() {
    Image = document.getElementById("Image");
    Filter = document.getElementById("Filter").value;

    Image.style.WebkitFilter = "grayscale(" + Filter * 10 + "%)"
}
```

**CSS**

```
img {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%);}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Pink_flower.jpg" id="Image" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">

<form>
    Photo Filter:
    <input type="range" id="Filter" name="points" min="0" max="10" onchange="ChangeFilter()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Anton -
I am using CSS filter properties to set new grayscale function value on an image element.

Comment: Yeah, but in a wrong way, a string should be encapsulated in quotes. Please, see my updated answer, I have fixed the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the grayscale value as a string.

I have simplified the code for you by using times, instead of ifs.

Also, you needed to set `-webkit-filter` and if you are starting at 100%, set the `value` to 10 to start with.

```css
img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" id="Image" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">

<form>
  Photo Filter:
  <input type="range" id="Filter" name="points" min="0" max="10" onchange="ChangeFilter()" value="10">

</form>

<script>
  function ChangeFilter() {

    var filter = document.getElementById("Filter").value;

    var greyScale = 'grayscale(' + (filter * 10) + '%)';

    document.getElementById("Image").style['-webkit-filter'] = greyScale;

    document.getElementById("Image").style.filter = greyScale;
  }
</script>
```